# Mulitple IF Statements based on other criteria

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, modern-experience

I have this and it works on its own:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Basic Finish]),"Past Due",IF([FCM 4 Expected Date]>[Basic Finish],"On Time",TEXT([FCM 4 Expected Date]-[Basic Finish],"h:m:ss")))
```

And

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Basic Finish]),"Past Due",IF([Expected End Date]>[Basic Finish],"On Time",TEXT([Expected End Date]-[Basic Finish],"h:mm:ss")))
```

I am trying to combine these into a single statement without success. I came up with this, but it just doesn't work.  What am I missing?

```
=IF([Work Order Type]<>"FCM4",IF(ISBLANK([Basic Finish]),"Past Due",IF([Expected End Date]>[Basic Finish],"On Time",TEXT([Expected End Date]-[Basic Finish],"h:m:ss"),IF([Work Order Type]="FCM4",IF(ISBLANK([Basic Finish]),"Past Due",IF([FCM 4 Expected Date]>[Basic Finish],"On Time",TEXT([FCM 4 Expected Date]-[Basic Finish],"h:mm:ss"))))))))
```

Comment: Could you provide a table of sample data with your expected result? This will help understand requirement quicker and build the logic around it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use below formula:

```
=IF([Work Order Type]="FCM4",IF(ISBLANK([Basic Finish]),"Past Due",IF([FCM 4 Expected Date]>[Basic Finish],"On Time",TEXT([FCM 4 Expected Date]-[Basic Finish],"h:m:ss"))),IF(ISBLANK([Basic Finish]),"Past Due",IF([Expected End Date]>[Basic Finish],"On Time",TEXT([Expected End Date]-[Basic Finish],"h:mm:ss"))))
```

**official references**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))
2. [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)